# get text inside a CSS font-awesome div icon

Tags: html, css

I have the following div layer:

```
<div class="iconfa-circle-blank"></div>
```

This shows me a font-awesome circle icon, I want to put a 1 character letter inside this  icon like this:

```
<div class="iconfa-circle-blank">A</div>
```

But the A character in this example doesn't go inside the div icon. I would like to have it go inside the icon and centered.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: a good solution will be to create a span with a class of "iconText" and in the "iconText" class just center it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `pseudo-element` *:before*.

I have made this for you so that you can see. You have to style it for your own, it's just to show you how it's done.

**http://jsfiddle.net/1BJK903/804jeg82/332/**

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro">A</i>

.fa:before {
    position: absolute;

}
```

So in your case, this would be:

```
<div class="iconfa-circle-blank">A</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.iconfa-circle-blank:before {
   position: absolute;
}
```

I would recommend using a **span** though. Wrap the text in a span and position it and style it like you want.